Should we do something about the [recipe-changing] tag?
Yesterday, I noticed that we have a tag called recipe-changing on the main site, with 11 questions using it.
Looking at the oldest question with it, I can imagine how it came into being - the question is Can I change a recipe sequencing (parallelising consecutive steps)?, and that is really an abstract question about possible changes to any recipe. But all the other questions are just everyday occasions of somebody cooking and not following their recipe to the letter.
I think that this is a bad tag. The alternatives I see so far are:
Leave it as-is
If we do that, the tag would fail a lot of the tests for a good tag.

It has no discriminatory purpose. A lot of questions we get are from people who are deviating from a recipe, my gut feeling would be that this would be at least a third of our questions, if not more.
It is used inconsistently/not discoverable. Most of the questions where people deviate from a concrete recipe do not use the tag.
It's not really an area of specialization. I haven't met cooks who describe themselves as "especially good at changing recipes" although I admit that some of them are better than others - but this might be simply a versatility that comes with broad experience, rather than specializing on purpose.

Make it about changing in general, not concrete recipes
We could decide to keep it, but make it applicable only when the OP wants to ask about the process of recipe changing in general, as opposed to "My recipe called for X but I did Y instead". I also see problems with this approach:

It has the opposite problem of the above: instead of covering too many questions, it covers too few (so far, a single one). If we don't get this kind of question, we don't need a tag for it!
It has a high chance of becoming one of those misunderstood tags, with people applying it intuitively to the concrete case, without reading the usage guidelines.

Remove it
I don't expect any downsides from that, but maybe there are some I haven't considered?

So my preferences would be to retag the one original question (efficiency comes to mind, but there may be better options), and remove it from the other questions, then let it slide into oblivion. What do you think?
